# infinite blinking cursor at top lefr corner of the screen after booting

Tags: boot

I started installing Ubuntu with unetbooting then I got so excited about the install that I forgot my charger wasn't plugged in, then my pc died, immediately I plugged it in and switched it on it showed me up as usual then moves to a dark screen (not purple Ubuntu screen) that has a cursor at the top left corner that blinks infinitely it's been blinking for the past hour now please help. I'VE got really important projects to do. Pleaaaaaaseeeee help me.

Comment: Try using rufus or dd to create your install usb; usb sticks made with unetbootin don't always work properly

Comment: I don't understand.

Comment: Are you creating the USB stick from Windows? If so, use the software **Rufus** instead of Unetbootin

Comment: I already used Unetbootin I created the usb already, till the point that I started installing Ubuntu then my system died, when I charged it and turned it on it got stuck at a dark screen with a cursor blinking at the top left corner

Comment: It sounds like it didn't complete the installation. Just boot into the USB installer and start the install process over again.

Comment: It isn't showing me the USB installer, don't you understand??

Comment: OK, then create the USB installer again using Unetbootin or Rufus, then boot into it to install Ubuntu

Comment: This is really crappy of Ubuntu, my first trial of the is and now my laptop is gone.

Comment: You let your battery die halfway through the installation of a new operating system... the same thing would happen with any other OS installation! Windows, Mac OS, whatever!

Comment: I have no access to my computer how will I do that?

Comment: You'll need to get access to another computer to create a USB installer, or install another operating system on your current one. Do you have a Windows recovery DVD? Or another flash drive with the Ubuntu installer on it? Or a recovery partition you can access through your BIOS?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the Ubuntu installer wasn't able to complete the installation due to the power outage. The solution is simple: just boot into the USB installer and start the install process over again.

Comment: Since I can't boot into the USB installer and Windows what then do I do?

Comment: Please see my latest comment on your question